# Flutter: how do I disable and enable play/pause flare animations?

Tags: flutter

Currently, both play and pause animations are showing up. The problem is when I press play, the pause button becomes visible but it is overlapping the play animation button. Also, pressing the button plays the audio on top of that is already playing.

Update May 11: Still looking for a solution. Currently, I'm having troubling making the flare pause animation button visible after I click the play animation button

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

class Omm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OmmState createState() => _OmmState();
}

class _OmmState extends State<Omm>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isPlaying = true;
  static bool isVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _audioCache = AudioCache(
        prefix: "audio/",
        fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));
  }

  var flay = Visibility(
    visible: !isVisible,
    child: FlareActor('assets/playbut3.flr',
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        color: Color(0xFF2a9d8f),
        animation: "playbutton"),
  );

  var fause = Visibility(
    visible: isVisible,
    child: FlareActor(
      'assets/pausebutton.flr',
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      color: Color(0xFF2a9d8f),
      animation: "pausebutton",
    ),
  );

  AudioCache _audioCache;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Animation")),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, 0.5),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: !_isPlaying ? fause : flay,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_isPlaying)
                  setState(() => isVisible = true);
                else
                  setState(() => isVisible = false);
                setState(() => _isPlaying = !_isPlaying);
                _audioCache.play('1min.mp3');
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the isPaused method provided by FlareActor

```
 FlareActor(
'assets/pausebutton.flr',
alignment: Alignment.center,
fit: BoxFit.contain,
isPaused: false,
color: Color(0xFF2a9d8f),
animation: "pausebutton",
```

),

where the value "false" will be boolean and you can put that variable that executes the Actor's action.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Visbility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) widget, and put a ternary as it's `visibility` so if it's playing it should hide the play button and display the pause button and vice versa.

like below:

```
class _OmmState extends State<Omm> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isPlaying = true;
  bool isVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _audioCache = AudioCache(
        prefix: "audio/",
        fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));
  }

  var flay = Visibility(
    visible: !isVisible,
    child: FlareActor('assets/playbut3.flr',
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        color: Color(0xFF2a9d8f),
        animation: "playbutton"),
  );

  var fause = Visibility(
    visible: isVisible,
    child: FlareActor(
      'assets/pausebutton.flr',
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      color: Color(0xFF2a9d8f),
      animation: "pausebutton",
    ),
  );

  AudioCache _audioCache;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Animation")),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, 0.5),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: !_isPlaying ? fause : flay,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_isPlaying)
                  setState(() => isVisible = true);
                else
                  setState(() => isVisible = false);
                setState(() => _isPlaying = !_isPlaying);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that but the pause button is overlapping the play button. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I updated the code in my original post.

Comment: I tried it out. I think we are getting somewhere. When I click play, play button disappears and I get an empty raised button instead of the flare pause animation. Also clicking on pause doesn't actually pause the audio.

Comment: i don't know why the `pause` button is empty, maybe it has to do something with how your animation works in your flare file.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you meant by "why the pause button is empty"? Should the play/pause be done in one animation file? because right now I have one animation for play and another separate animation for pause.

Comment: can you share a link to your animation files?

Comment: sure. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/05bca704ef67317151f4f8e1f8ecd1da20200510195035/f0b8a31ecddd77c2bb2716c435e849b320200510195104/41ec73

Comment: i actually need them in flare itself.

Comment: I just edited play and pause in the same project. Here is the pause file. Let me know if you need the play one too. I can quickly re-make it
https://rive.app/a/losee/files/flare/pausebutton

Comment: i am sorry i can't seem to find the problem, post the link of your question [here](https://discord.com/channels/420324994703163402/421445316617961502) or [here](https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter) maybe someone can help you.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help!